# How to capture stderr on Windows/DOS?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, cmd, stderr

I want to capture the errors from a script into a file instead of to the screen.

In *nix, this is done with stderr redirection, usually

```
echo "Error" 2> errorfile.log
```

How do I do it in a CMD script under Windows?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For example:

```
PSKILL NOTEPAD >output.txt 2>&1
```

This will direct stdout and stderr to a file name output.txt.

See [Underused features of Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/underused-features-of-windows-batch-files#246691) for more details.

Comment: If you want them redirected to separate files, you can do `mycommand >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`

Answer (score 20):

That should work in Win32, too.

If you have already redirected stdout, and want stderr redirected to the same file, you must use the 2>& special form, rather than just specifying the same file twice. Otherwise you'll get a "file busy" error.

Comment: This is also covered in *[Redirect stdout and stderr to a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965)*.