# How to redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, pipe

I'm trying to redirect all output (stdout + stderr) of a [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) to a single file:

```
C:\>dir 1> a.txt 2> a.txt
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Is it possible, or should I just redirect to two separate files?

Comment: TechNet: [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) (answers this better than any of the answers here).

Comment: 2>&1 as it can't reopen the same file

Answer (score 1343, accepted):

You want:

```
dir > a.txt 2>&1
```

The syntax `2>&1` will redirect `2` (stderr) to `1` (stdout). You can also hide messages by redirecting to `NUL`. More explanation and examples are on the Microsoft documentation page [Redirecting error messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/language-compilers/redirecting-error-command-prompt).

Comment: this is great for hiding all output.. `net stop w3svc >NUL 2>&1`.. thanks!

Comment: @wasatchwizard Ithink I had trouble with that, but >NUL 2>NUL worked fine

Comment: If there is a Handle, there cannot be a space between the Handle (i.e. 2) and the redirect operator (i.e. >). Therefore `2> 2.txt` works  (or `2> &1`)  `2 > 2.txt` does not; `2 > &1` does not.

Comment: if you want to append, use >> instead of > i.e. dir >> a.txt 2>&1 it is very useful for system logs and exeptions.

Comment: Perhaps add some information as per [DelboyJays answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file/16713357#16713357) *after* note?

Comment: *>NUL would this work?

Comment: what does the & here do ?

Answer (score 241):

Anders Lindahl's answer is correct, but it should be noted that if you are redirecting stdout to a file and want to redirect stderr as well then you MUST ensure that `2>&1` is specified **AFTER** the `1>` redirect, otherwise it will not work.

```
REM *** WARNING: THIS WILL NOT REDIRECT STDERR TO STDOUT ****
dir 2>&1 > a.txt
```

Comment: Is it explaned anywhere why putting 2>&1 before 1> will not achieved the intended effect? I strongly suspect this has got to do with the way "cmd" parses commands that gives two different meanings depending on the order in which you specify the redirection. But are the semantic rules documented anywhere because I reckon this is something worthwhile to learn as it could waste hours.

Comment: @igbgotiz 2>&1 means 'redirect stream 2 to stream 1'. So you need to set up stream 1 first

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave but stream 1 is standard output (e.g. console) if not explicitly specified. That still does not explain it imho.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, if you do `dir 2>&1 > a.txt`, you're first redirecting (`>`) stream 2 (stderr) to stream 1 (stdout). Then, after both of them are already joined together, you're redirecting stdout (`>` with no specifier) to the file. If you want stderr to go somewhere else, you can't join it with stdout first.

Comment: @cp.engr that still explains nothing because then the rational question: why does it work this way in pretty much every other shell, i.e. sh, zsh, bash, etc.

Comment: @cp.engr I replied to your explanation for why redirection to a file in cmd shell should be before redirection of stderr → stdout.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I see that. You asked "why does *it* work *this way* in pretty much every other shell...?", suggesting that there are contexts where my explanation does not apply. I don't know what you're talking about. So again, why does *what* work *what way*?

Comment: @cp.engr I mean that in every other shell I know of, it's allowed to set redirection to a file after stderr → stdout to redirect both of them.

Comment: The usual way to do that is to use `tee` which allows something to go to a file, and still go to stdout/stderr. If you redirect a stream, it doesn't still go to the original destination. It's been redirected.

Comment: Good additional info regarding `append` instead of `create` (use >>).

Comment: In case of appending to log, is it necessary to use `>>` only for the stdout redirection or also for `2>&1`, so that it will be like `2>>&1` ?

Comment: maybe a simple way to understand this is 2>&1 dups the stream. So if you dup it before 1 is redirected, you're pointing to a copy of the original output location.  If you dup it after, you're point to a copy of the new location.

Comment: This "do not do this" answer is not an answer. It should have been a comment on the top rated answer.

Answer (score 100):

### Background info from Microsoft documentation

While the accepted answer to this question is correct, it really doesn't do much to explain *why* it works, and since the syntax is not immediately clear I did a quick www search to find out what was actually going on. In the hopes that this information is helpful to others, I'm posting it here.

Taken from the Microsoft documentation page:
[Redirecting error messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/language-compilers/redirecting-error-command-prompt)

> #### Summary
>
> When redirecting output from an application using the `>` symbol, error messages still print to the screen. This is because error messages are often sent to the Standard Error stream instead of the Standard Out stream.
>
> Output from a console (Command Prompt) application or command is often sent to two separate streams. The regular output is sent to Standard Out (STDOUT) and the error messages are sent to Standard Error (STDERR). When you redirect console output using the `>` symbol, you are only redirecting STDOUT. In order to redirect STDERR, you have to specify `2>` for the redirection symbol. This selects the second output stream that is STDERR.
>
> #### Example
>
> The command `dir file.xxx` (where file.xxx does not exist) will display the following output:
>
> > Volume in drive F is Candy Cane Volume Serial Number is 34EC-0876
> > File Not Found
>
> If you redirect the output to the NUL device using `dir file.xxx > nul`, you will still see the error message:
>
> > File Not Found
>
> To redirect the error message to NUL, use the following command:
>
> ```
> dir file.xxx 2> nul
> ```
>
> Or, you can redirect the output to one place, and the errors to another.
>
> ```
> dir file.xxx > output.msg 2> output.err
> ```
>
> You can print the errors and standard output to a single file by using the `&1` command to redirect the output for STDERR to STDOUT and then sending the output from STDOUT to a file:
>
> ```
> dir file.xxx 1> output.msg 2>&1
> ```

Answer (score 45):

To add the stdout and stderr to the general logfile of a script:

```
dir >> a.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: The `>>` appends to the file where the `>` overwrites the file.

Answer (score 15):

Correct, file handle 1 for the process is STDOUT, redirected by the `1>` or by `>` (1 can be omitted, by convention, the command interpreter [cmd.exe] knows to handle that).
File handle 2 is STDERR, redirected by `2>`.

Note that if you're using these to make log files, then unless you're sending the outut to _uniquely_named_ (eg date-and-time-stamped) log files, then if you run the same process twice, the redirected will overwrite (replace) the previous log file.

The `>>` (for either STDOUT or STDERR) will APPEND not REPLACE the file. So you get a cumulative logfile, showwing the results from all runs of the process - typically more useful.

Happy trails...

Answer (score 5):

There is, however, no guarantee that the output of `SDTOUT` and `STDERR` are interweaved line-by-line in timely order, using the `POSIX` redirect merge syntax.

If an application uses buffered output, it may happen that the text of one stream is inserted in the other at a buffer boundary, which may appear in the middle of a text line.

A dedicated console output logger (I.e. the `"StdOut/StdErr Logger"` by `'LoRd MuldeR'`) may be more reliable for such a task.

See: [MuldeR's OpenSource Projects](http://muldersoft.com/)

Answer (score 4):

In a batch file (Windows 7 and above) I found this method most reliable

```
Call :logging >"C:\Temp\NAME_Your_Log_File.txt" 2>&1
:logging
TITLE "Logging Commands"
ECHO "Read this output in your log file"
ECHO ..
Prompt $_
COLOR 0F
```

Obviously, use whatever commands you want and the output will be directed to the text file.
Using this method **is** reliable HOWEVER there is NO output on the screen.

Comment: (basically the same answer given a few times years ago.) You can force output to screen with `>con echo This goes to screen` Also useful for user input `>con set /p "var="Input: "` Note: those lines will *only* appear on screen and *not* be redirected to the file.