# RedirectStandardOutput when the main application exits using F#

Tags: f#, process, redirectstandardoutput

Assume the following code:

```
let sw = new StreamWriter("out.txt", false)
sw.AutoFlush <- true

let proc = new Process()
proc.StartInfo.FileName <- path
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
proc.OutputDataReceived.Add(fun b -> sw.WriteLine b.Data )
proc.Start() |> ignore
proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

I create a process and exit the main application. The process is still running (as it should) but it stops redirecting the standard output. Is there any way how to continue writing the standard output to the file even after the main application exits?

PS: I have to exit the main application and cannot wait for the process to finish
PPS: I would like to do a similar thing for the standard error output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think desco's answer may work if `RedirectStandardOutput` is false. The output isn't being written to the file after your process exits because the `OutputDataReceived` event handler no longer exists. If possible, I'd recommend passing the output file path to your program (assume no path means write to stdout). With that in place it should be easy to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, a good point. Sometimes I do not see the most simple and obvious ways to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

can you perform redirect by starting process with proper command line: [Redirect stdout and stderr to a single file in dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file-in-dos)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to do: `proc.StartInfo.Arguments <- arguments + " 1> -Out.txt"` but it does not seem to work. I get the output in the fsi console.

Comment: @Oldrich: That may not be working because of `RedirectStandardOutput <- true`.