# Displaying and copying output of a java program from command prompt into a file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, java-io

i have a Java program which takes input from Users and displays output according to the input. The Program provides the user with a menu of options and the user is required to select one option from the menu.

Now i have to run this program through a batch file and stream the output of this program into another file. I achieve this by using the following code in the bat file.

```
java -jar ./dist/MP4.jar > ./docs/mp4out.txt
```

But when this bat file is run the command prompt will never display the menu and ask the user input as all the java program output is redirected into the file. So my question is how can i make the command prompt to show the menu and wait for the user input and also redirect all the programs output into a file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `System.out.println()` use `System.err.println()` for the menu output. then your redirect will only capture what is sent to System.out (STDOUT) and not want goes to System.err.

Note: the above is a bit of hack, why not change your code to write to the output file instead of requiring redirect?  You could make it optional and write to stdout if needed.

This is kind of the inverse of what you want: [Redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file-in-dos)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, all you would have to do is allow the user to enter something in a while loop, such as

```
    while(userInput != optionThatEndsMenu) { askInput....}
```

Then, just use PrintWriter to create a new file such as

```
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(<fileName>);
    outputFile.println(//whatever you have to output goes here);
```

and that should print the contents of the program into the file.

Answer (score 0):

A Tee filter is the traditional method to redirect to a file and the screen at the same time.