# How can I redirect console output to file?

Tags: c, shell, io-redirection

I'm new to c.
Is there any simple way to redirect all the console's output (printfs etc.) to a file using some general command line \ linkage parameter (without having to modify any of the original code)?

If so what is the procedure?

Comment: [Yes of course there is](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout and stderr to a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use shell output redirection

`your-command > outputfile.txt`

The standard error will still be output to the console.  If you don't want that, use:

`your-command > outputfile.txt 2>&1`

or

`your-command &> outputfile.txt`

You should also look into the `tee` utility, which can make it redirect to two places at once.

Comment: don't forget >> to append to the file

Answer (score 3):

On unices, you can also do:

```
your-command | tee output file.txt
```

That way you'll see the output and be able to interact with the program, while getting a hardcopy of the standard output (but not standard input, so it's not like a teletype session).

Comment: while ssh to a server using this command can save whole session file. Awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, you can use the > operator to redirect the output of your program to a file as in:

```
./program > out_file
```

Also, you can append data to an existing file (or create it if it doesnt exit already by using >> operator:

```
./program >> out_file
```

If you really want to learn more about the (awesome) features that the command line has to offer I would really recommend reading this book (and doing lots of programming :))

http://linuxcommand.org/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

In Unix shells you can usually do `executable > file 2> &1`, whch means "redirect standard output to *file* and error output to standard output"