# Print result of java -version to file -> Why is resulting file empty?

Tags: java, windows

`java -version` correctly prints Java version. `java -version >> test.txt` creates an empty file. My problem is that WScript.Shell has exactly the same behavior (empty string returned). Why does this happen, and how to get things right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect console output to file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155744/how-can-i-redirect-console-output-to-file)

Comment: its not. The post you linked does not work, as this was not the problem. See the anwer of Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`java -version` displays the version information on standard *error* rather than standard *output*... so you need to redirect that:

```
java -version 2>> test.txt
```

Here the `2>>` means "redirect standard error, appending it to the given file".