# Can we save the execution log when we run a command using PuTTY/Plink

Tags: linux, cmd, putty, plink

I am using Plink to run a command on remote machine. In order to fully automate the process I 
need to save the execution log somewhere. I am using a bat file:

```
C:\Ptty\plink.exe root@<IP> -pw <password> -m C:\Ptty\LaunchFile.txt
```

The `C:\Ptty\LaunchFile.txt` contains my command that i want to run.

```
./Launch.sh jobName=<job name> restart.mode=false
```

Is there a way to save the execution log so that I can monitor it later...  ?

Answer (score 1):

The `plink` is a console application. Actually that's probably it's only purpose. As such, its output can be redirected to a file as with any other command-line command/tool.

Following example redirects both standard and error output to a file `output.log`:

```
plink.exe -m script.txt username@example.com > output.log 2>&1
```

See also [Redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1420965/850848).

Answer (score 0):

This is the one of my way to log everything when I use putty.exe on Windows.

[image]