# How to fetch data from putty window using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I know this might be a silly question. I want to login to putty and read the lines in putty window. The following code gets stuck at the **readline**.

```
Dim UserName
Dim Passwrd

UserName = InputBox("Please Enter Your UserID:")
Passwrd  = InputBox("Please Enter Your Password:")

Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
pcmd = "C:\Putty\putty.exe -ssh"&" "&UserName & "@10.x.xx.x -pw" &" "&Passwrd 

Set exec = shell.Exec(pcmd)
Set pout = exec.StdOut
Dim strFromPutty 
Do
    strFromPutty = pout.ReadLine
    print strFromPutty
Loop While Not pout.AtEndOfStream
```

Comment: Use `plink` rather than `putty` if you want to process output from the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

you may not be able to do that. The session might be a different process started by putty.

I propose to redirect it to a file and read it from there:
Full answer here: [Save PuTTY ouput to file from command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477658/save-putty-ouput-to-file-from-command-line)