# how to save the output in the command prompt to a txt file

Tags: command-prompt

I tried using `2>`, but it still doesn't save the error in the text file.

```
C:\>telnet abc 2> test.txt
Connecting To abc...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1420981)

Answer (score 0):

Use `>>` to append the output of a command (for either STDOUT or STDERR) to a file:

```
C:>telnet abc >> test.txt
```

Comment: This would not redirect STDERR to the file

Comment: @koukouviou quoted from an answer of the question you've linked, "The >> (for either STDOUT or STDERR) will APPEND not REPLACE the file. So you get a cumulative logfile, showwing the results from all runs of the process - typically more useful."

Comment: ya. this is not work. The text.txt still showing empty