# Get details of an S3 sync failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We run S3 sync commands in a SQL Job which syncs a local directory to an S3 bucket.  At times, we'll get a sync "error" with an error code of 1, or sometimes 2.  The documentation lists what each code means; error code 1 provides less details and leaves more questions remaining about the problem.  It simply states "One or more Amazon S3 transfer operations failed.  Limited to S3 commands."

When I run a sync command in a PowerShell script, and encounter an error (i.e. a synced document being open), the window displays an error message and which specific file that is causing a problem.

How can I capture those details in my SQL job?

Comment: Looking at this post again after a couple of months and I see why it didn't garner many responses - It needs focus.  The real question at hand is in regards to error code 1:  What is the likely problem in those cases?

Comment: For anyone following along, I've discovered from this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/35076194/16577485 that I can react to error code 1 and route the output to a text file, possibly then learning which file(s) failed.  Will post back my results.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem...

Using a PowerShell script, in the AWS s3 sync command we output the results to a text file:

`aws s3 sync c:\source\dir  s3://target/dir/ > F:\Source\s3Inventory\SyncOutput.txt`

Then read the text file contents into a string variable:

`$S3Output = Get-Content -Path C:\Source\s3Inventory\SyncOutput.txt -Raw`

If the $LASTEXITCODE from the sync command does not equal 0 (indicating an error), then we send an email with the results:

```
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
    {   
        #Send email containing the value of string variable $S3Output        
    }
```

This has been placed into production and we were finally able to determine which file/object was failing.

One could certainly attach the text file to the email, rather than reading the contents into a string.

Hope this helps others!