# Windows redirect stdout and stderr to a file

Tags: python, windows, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the output of a python script to a file. I have run:

```
C:\>python c:\python_script.py > a.txt 2>&1
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file#) but output is only written once the process completes or is killed. Is there a way to have the redirection write to file as output is written to stdout & stderr?

Comment: Not unless Python itself provides such a mechanism.  (Question retagged in the hopes of attracting the attention of a Python expert.)

Comment: Why not use Python's logging module in the `python_script`? Then you can log anywhere in the script in real time

Comment: That's an option, but a Windows solution would be ideal (eg: what if I didn't have the Python source, or if it was a different program?)