# How to hide 'net use' command error message in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to delete `y:` drive that mapped to a network directory using this line of batch script.

```
net use y: /d /y>nul
```

But in the situations `y:` doesn't exist of already deleted. it gives me this error message.

```
The network connection could not be found.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

Is there a way to avoid printing this error? I have tried `net use y: /d /y>nul>nul` but no luck

Comment: DelboyJay answer here: [Redirect stdout and stderr to a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file)

Answer (score 8):

You could not cause an error in the first place:

```
if exist y:\ net use y: /delete
```

Answer (score 4):

You should write it like that to redirect the error to nul :

```
@echo off
net use y: /d /y>nul 2>&1
pause
```

Take a look at : ***[I/O Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)***