# Why does redirecting into file behave differently on windows?

Tags: windows, redirect

There is a ton of questions relating windows-redirecting, but I can't find anything on this (trivial?) behaviour.

I want to redirect some git-for-windows output into a file. Redirections like these work:

```
$ dir > test.txt
$ dir test > test.txt
$ ipconfig /all > t
```

est.txt

But this one outputs to the terminal and creates an empty file:

```
$ java -version > test.txt
```

This one outputs to a file correctly, but not if I invoke it from my IDE (which is IAR):

```
$ git --version > test.txt
```

The latest case is the one most interesting for me. How do I get the output of any executed program redirected into a file?

Comment: "java -version" goes to stderr.

Comment: *How do I get the output of any executed program redirected into a file?* - you don't.  Both of those examples probably just write to `stderr` rather than `stdout`, but some programs really do write explicitly to the console.  That's the programmer's decision.  You can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
git --version > test.txt 2>&1
```

[origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420981/126995)

Comment: Thanks, this one works for the `java -version`, as it apparently goes to `stderr`. `git --version` goes to `stdout`, as I can redirect it to a file when I invoke it directly.
However, *both* redirections don't work, when I invoke the batch script from my IDE (IAR). It only creates an empty file `test.txt`.