# Plink fails to run when executed from PHP in wamp, but works when executed manually

Tags: php, batch-file, wamp, exec, plink

I need to access a Linux machine from Windows 7 via PHP.

For that I created simple bat (`MyScript.bat`) script containing plink.

```
c:\wamp\www\abc\plink.exe user1@192.168.70.128 -pw l1c -C "df -h">11.txt
```

When I am executing the bat script, it's working fine, i.e. the output is written in file `11.txt`

But when I am accessing it from PHP, the `11.txt` is created without data

```
echo exec('MyScript.bat');
```

Moreover, in browser, the script commands are displayed as text. I even tried to use `print_r` for the display.

```
"c:\wamp\www\abc\plink.exe user1@192.168.70.128 -pw l1c -C "df -h">11.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not launch external tool for SSH.

PHP has [native support for SSH](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php).

Or use [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

$ssh = new SSH2($hostname);
if ($ssh->login($username, $password))
{
    echo $ssh->exec("df -h");
}
```

See:

- https://phpseclib.com/docs/connect
- https://phpseclib.com/docs/auth

---

Anyway, if you want to use Plink, redirect also the standard error output to debug your problem:

```
plink.exe .. dir > 11.txt 2>&1
```

See [How to redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1420965/850848).

You are for sure missing the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) to explicitly specify a fingerprint of the trusted hostkey.