# What is "2" in command, while redirecting both System.out , System.err Java messages to file

Tags: java, windows, redirect, error-handling, out

I just figured that, we can redirect both `System.out` and `System.err` messages to  a file, am not able to understand this command which does redirecting while running this below file using : `java StandarProgram> output.log 2>error.log`

What is 2? and if am not using 2, error messages are displayed on console and not redirected to file? am not able to get this at all.

```
public class StandardProgram{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       System.out.println("Hello");
       System.err.println("World");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 is a standard error file descriptor.

File descriptor 1 is the standard output (stdout).
File descriptor 2 is the standard error (stderr).

```
2>error.log
```

is used to redirect the standard error logs to a file named error.log

Answer (score 1):

System.out is according to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) Standard Output Stream - it is 1

System.err is according to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err) Standard Error Stream - it is 2

Comment: what are these, exactly 1 & 2? does they help to  represent content?

Comment: those are file descriptors for linux systems

1 means standard output file descriptor
2 means standard error file descriptor

Comment: am using windows, is it same with windows? and other OS

Comment: yes, it is

Here is your code snippet in windows cmd: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file