# Putting mongorestore output into a file

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

Is there a way to put the mongorestore output it spits out from the command line into a file? This is for Linux/Unix

`mongorestore --port $MONGO_PORT --db $database --archive=$BACKUP_NAME.archive >> log_file` creates an empty file.

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file

Comment: Yep it works fine thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `dir > a.txt 2>&1` or something along the lines of that solved my issue.