# Laravel 4 routes display part

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have an app with really long list of routes. Is it possible to limit the output of the routes to show part on the screen and then by pressing enter seeing the rest of them. Kind of like if you would do `less artisan routes`?

Comment: [Redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file). Use `php artisan routes > routes.txt 2>&1`, output will be saved into **routes.txt**

Comment: how many routes do you have, why do you need to paginate them ?