# How to write to a file by using (or changing) print using Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pycharm, interactive-brokers

Im using an API from Interactive Brokers to get historical data and I am using their code to download the data.

The code uses the print function to output the data to the terminal, but I would like to redirect it to a file (lets call that file StockData.txt)

The code I am using is:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print("HistoricalData. ", reqId, " Date:", bar.date, "Open:", bar.open, "High:", bar.high, "Low:", bar.low, "Close:", bar.close, "Volume:", bar.volume)

def main():
    app = TestApp()

    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0)

    contract = Contract ()
    contract.symbol = "AAPL"
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.primaryExchange = "NASDAQ"

    app.reqHistoricalData(0, contract, "", "1 D", "1 min", "TRADES", 0, 1, False, [])

    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Like I said, I would like the API to write to StockData.txt, but I am unsure how to do this since it's not my code and I am not that savvy in Python.

Could anyone help me out here?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just using standard OS output redirection instead of modifying the script? For how to do that on windows, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file

Comment: Hi GPhilo, I am unsure what you mean by that. Could you clarify please?

Comment: GPhilo, thank you for the append, but I am not able to use that form for my problem.

Comment: Perhaps more info on why you're not able may help us helping you to solve te issue. Can you clrify?

Comment: The link you send does not talk about printing or writing, but redirecting something with a line of code. i don't think I can use that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while it would probably be better to do output redirection:

```
python my_script.py > outputfile.txt
```

to actually overwrite any function is pretty simple:

```
def print_to_file(*args):
    with open('text.txt', 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(' '.join(map(str,args)))
print = print_to_file
```

just plop the above lines of code somewhere high in you script
this is **not** the recommended way though, because it will only overwrite `print` in the current script and not in the imported modules which may also be printing

A better way is to change your `stdout`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('text.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: First option (overwriting print) only works for the printing done in the current script: if any of the imported modules writes to the terminal, that part won't be written to file. The correct way (aside from the redirection) is to change `stdout`