# How to write to a text or csv file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In images folder, I have 10 images of my face and I used face detection for each image in the folder. How can I put these results from my code below in a CSV file or a text file?

```
########     Full code face detection ################
from cv2 import *
import numpy
import glob
import sys
import random

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

path = "C:\Users\laptop\PycharmProjects\TestProjects\images\*.jpg"

for file in glob.glob(path):

    a= imread(file)
    Green = a[:, :, 1]  

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(Green, 1.3, 5) 

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

        roi_gray = Green[y:y + h, x:x + w]


    avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(roi_gray, axis=0)

    avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)

    print(avg_color)

######### the results that I obtained like this ############ 
69.91705606204184
70.66349480968857
69.041945839532
70.1554508228386
70.99404075355632
70.78112050920586
70.3311333247896
70.55470990048913
69.97209406638471
69.85739459182365
```

Comment: Python provides `csv` module to read/write csv files - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Can you tell us,what did you try?

Comment: I tried to average all pixcels in the face region

Answer (score 0):

As [Shiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3007402/shiva) answered above, you can use the [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to output your result as a Csv file. This would be the pythonic way. There is a simpler solution as well.

Both Windows and *Nix Os'es support command redirection (eg: [redirect windows cmd stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file)). You can use this technique to create a csv file based on the output of your program.

Explore modifying the last statement (`print(avg_color)`) to match the desired csv output and when you run the script redirect the output (via `>`) to a csv file.