# Windows Redirect STDERR and STDOUT to same program when piping

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, stdout, stderr

[MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file) give an example of redirecting Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file:

```
dir file.xxx 1> output.msg 2>&1
```

I'm looking to do the same when the STDERR and STDOUT are piped to another program.  Here's the usage without the STDERR redirects:

```
net use Z: \\server\share  |  TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt
```

I want the STDERR and STDOUT of "net use" to be piped into TimeStampPipe.exe.  I don't care about STDERR from TimeStampPipe.exe.  Where does the 2>&1 go to indicate that it applies to net use and not to TimeStampPipe.exe?  I tried this

```
net use Z: \\server\share  1> 2>&1 TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt
```

and got `2>&1 was unexpected at this time.`

I tried this

```
net use Z: \\server\share  1| 2|&1 TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt
```

and got `& was unexpected at this time.`

Is there a way to do this when piping?  I could try something like:

```
net use Z: \\server\share  1> tempfile.txt 2>&1
type tempfile.txt | TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt 
del tempfile.txt
```

Is there a more concise approach?

Edit: I tried the suggestion of @compo to use `2>&1` alone. I tried these three forms:

```
net use Z: \\server\share  | 2>&1 TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt 
net use Z: \\server\share  |  TimeStampPipe.exe 2>&1 >> logfile.txt 
net use Z: \\server\share  | TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt 2>&1
```

In each case, the stdout is correctly piped, but any stderr output from net use goes to the screen, not through the pipe.

Comment: If you think about it, StdOut doesn't normally need to be specifically redirected for piping, does it? So when you want to include StdErr, you'd just add it on its own. I'd therefore offer, just `2>&1`, _(i.e. send handle 2 to wherever handle 1 is going)_, instead of `1> 2>&1`

Comment: That makes sense, but doesn't work. See above for the formats I tried. In all cases, stderr goes to the screen (cmd window), not the pipe.

Comment: Did you try `net use Z: \\server\share 2>&1 | TimeStampPipe.exe >>logfile.txt`? You want STDERR from the `net use` command, right?

Comment: I'm sorry tim11g, I thought it was obvious, when I said redirection for piping, that the redirection was to be performed before the pipe! Please take a look at @SomethingDark's [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62250716/windows-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-same-program-when-piping#comment110097393_62250716) to see what I meant.

Comment: Yes that's it.  I was following the pattern from the articles of putting `2>&1` after the operative redirect, but clearly in the case if pipe it must come first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already pointed out in comments you have to do this:

```cmd
net use Z: \\server\share 2>&1 | TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt
```

---

You already have got the right code to redirect both *STDOUT* and *STDERR* to a file:

```cmd
dir file.xxx 1> output.msg 2>&1
```

which is the same as:

```cmd
dir file.xxx > output.msg 2>&1
```

because output redirection (`>`) reads from *STDOUT* (handle `1`) by default.

The expression `2>&1` defines that handle `2` (*STDERR*) is to be redirected to the destination that handle `1` (*STDOUT*) is currently (re-)directed to. The position of that expression is crucial.

---

For a pipe (`|`) you have to apply the same technique. Remember that a pipe redirects the output (at *STDOUT*, handle `1`) of the left-side command into the input (at *STDIN*, handle `0`) of the right-side command.

Now we want to redirect both *STDOUT* and *STDERR* of the left side into *STDIN* of the right side. Since nothing changes for the right side we keep it untouched. The left side however needs to be modified; *STDOUT* already goes where we want to, but *STDERR* does not yet, so we have to redirect it to the target of *STDOUT*, by using the same expression as for output redirection (`>`):

```cmd
net use Z: \\server\share 2>&1 | TimeStampPipe.exe >> logfile.txt
```