# How to write standard error in text file using batch command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename, batch-updates

For one file it's showing standard error on console i.e. command prompt. I want to print it on  text file.

Comment: Google knows the answer, just ask for `How to write standard error in text file using batch command`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture stderr on Windows/DOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482678/how-to-capture-stderr-on-windows-dos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
some_file.exe >> text.file 2>&1
```

this will print all output to text file[.For more info.](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

Comment: I found a similar page on Microsoft's site: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Yes.This is the official MS documentation , but I find robvandervoude page a little bit more neat.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
command 2>file
```

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930