# Sending Java Version to textfile

Tags: java, command

I have to send the java version to a text file as below

```
C:\>java -version > C:\cfn\log\JavaVersion.log
```

But when i open the check the file, its completely Empty. I get the version immediately at the below line as-

```
C:\>java -version > C:\cfn\log\JavaVersion.log
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Look at the dup and the answers. They like to others as well. java is sending this information to stderr. This is a common practive. PowerShell sees it as a fault.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will create a file on the current path.

```
java -version > JavaVersion.log 2>&1
```

or this one, which will create file on the specified path

```
java -version > C:\cfn\log\JavaVersion.log 2>&1
```

The syntax `2>&1` will redirect `2 (stderr)` to `1 (stdout)`. You can also hide messages by redirecting to  `NUL`

Comment: improved my answer, check it again.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking out for.. You made my day. Thanks much :)

Comment: When I try the same thing in powershell as `& java -version > C:\JavaVersion.log 2>&1`, & when I try opening the file's content, the below is what I see-

`java.exe : java version "1.8.0_121"
At line:1 char:1
+ & java -version > C:\JavaVersion.log 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (java version "1.8.0_121":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13
)


Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)`.

Comment: This fixed the above `& cmd /c "java -version > C:\javaVersion.log 2>&1"`

Answer (score 0):

On my mac,

```
java -version
```

prints to stderr.

To redirect stderr to a file, do something like:

```
java -version 2> foo.txt
```

For how to do this on Windows, see:

[How to capture stderr on Windows/DOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482678/how-to-capture-stderr-on-windows-dos)

Comment: This is the perfect one. Thanks much :)