# Get value with certain prefix from JSON

Tags: json, batch-file, cmd

I have a .json file and want to extract the value for a certain key - but the key occurs multiple times (because the JSON contains a list of arrays). But I know that the value I am looking for starts with a certain prefix, so I wrote this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %%a in (' find ":" ^< "myjson.json" ') do (
    if "%%~a"=="mykey" (
        set VALUE_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT=%%~b
        echo b: %%~b
        echo var: %VALUE_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT%
        IF "%VALUE_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT:~0,8%"=="myprefix" (
            goto leave
        )
    )
)
:leave
```

prints:

```
b: myprefixvalue
var:
b: othervalue1
var: 
b: othervalue2
var:
```

When I REM out the line `echo b: %%~b` I get:

```
var: othervalue2
var: othervalue2
var: othervalue2
```

What happens here? And how do I get the value I am looking for?

Comment: An example of the input file would help to see.

Comment: Use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your .cmd. And use `!VALUE_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT!` instead of `%VAL...%` in the `for` loop body.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Great, this works! Can you explain why?

Comment: The immediate `%VAR%` expansion syntax expands the variable at *parsing time*, so when the entire line or `(`block`)` of code is read; to expand a variable during *execution time*, there is a feature called [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which looks like `!VAR!` after having been enabled by a preceding `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable in a 'for' loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373307/use-a-variable-in-a-for-loop)