# merge files in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a long list of files that I want to merge into few files.

```
part-m-00000 
part-m-00001 
part-m-00002 
part-m-00003
part-m-00004
part-m-00005
part-m-00006
part-m-00007
part-m-00008
part-m-00009
part-m-00010
part-m-00011
part-m-00012
...
part-m-01267
```

(Notice the padding of number at the end of the file name)

I want to merge every 100 files into 10 individual files and the last remaining 67 into the 11th. I'm having trouble padding those numbers to merge the files.

Here's what I was able to get to -

```
@echo off
if exist merge.txt del merge.txt

echo. >merge.txt
for /l %%a in (0,1,3) do (
Set Number=00000%%a
Set Number=%Number:~-5%
copy/b merge.txt+"part-m-%number%.txt" merge.txt
)
```

I don't think the padding of numbers is working as expected. It just doesn't work for me in the `for` loop. If I do something like this in general -

```
Set Number=768
Set Number=00000%Number%
Set Number=%Number:~-5%
echo %Number%
```

it correctly pads the number.

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Umm shouldn't the last remaining 67 be in the 13th?

Comment: oops. 13th is what i meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables with the `%XXX%` are expanded only once for the `for` loop, not in every iteration.

You need to use delayed expansion with the `!XXX!` syntax like this:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%a in (0,1,3) do (
Set Number=00000%%a
Set Number=!Number:~-5!
echo !Number!
)
```

For more details refer to question [Batch file variables initialized in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/691047/850848).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist merge.txt del merge.txt

echo. >merge.txt
for /l %%a in (0,1,3) do (
Set Number=00000%%a
Set Number=!Number:~-5!
copy /b merge.txt+"part-m-%number%.txt" merge.txt
)
```

If you do not use delayed expansion, the variable `%Number:~-5%` will be expanded only once - before the whole `for` command is processed. With delayed expansion used, the variable `!Number:~-5!` will be expanded each time it is run, so the number will be different each time.

Answer (score 0):

Another (perhaps simpler and faster) approach is this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist merge.txt del merge.txt

echo. >merge.txt
set Number=99999
for /l %%a in (0,1,3) do (
Set /A Number+=1
copy /b merge.txt+"part-m-!Number:~-5!.txt" merge.txt
)
```