# Why is displayed always the same file name on running a FOR loop which should find *.exe files and output their names?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want that my batch script only shows the filename without any path or extension in a specific directory of *.exe files. My code so far is this:

```
for /R "%cd%" %%e in (*.exe) do (
    set "EXENAME=%%~ne"
    echo "%EXENAME%"
)
```

But this code does not work as expected. Let's assume, I have two files in that directory: `tomcat7.exe` and `tomcat7w.exe`. But when processing the script, I get as an answer this:

```
"tomcat7w"
"tomcat7w"
```

Why is that?

Comment: why aren't you using the `dir` command ?

Comment: See `set /?`, `for /?`, and `setlocal /?` (enabledelayedexpansion).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file variables initialized in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691047/batch-file-variables-initialized-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

You ran into the delayed expansion trap as so many batch file coding newbies as [Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6017774/noodles) hinted.

You could see the expected result by using `echo %%~ne` instead of `echo "%EXENAME%"`.

By opening a command prompt window, running in this window `set /?` and reading the output help you get delayed environment variable expansion explained on an **IF** and a **FOR** example.

The batch file producing the expected output:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "%cd%" %%e in (*.exe) do (
    set "EXENAME=%%~ne"
    echo !EXENAME!
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see with extensions try like this way :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "%cd%" %%e in (*.exe) do (
    set "EXENAME=%%~nxe"
    echo !EXENAME!
)
endlocal
pause
```