# In Batch variable not printing

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a batch file to kill all the dependent process for given process ID.I have not completed my code yet.For now my code is

```
set cmd="wmic process where (ParentProcessId=4192) get ProcessId"
FOR /F %%i IN (' %cmd% ') DO ( 
SET X=%%i 
echo The process is %X%
)
```

The output of "wmic process where (ParentProcessId=4192) get ProcessId" command is :

```
ProcessID
3516
<blank space>
```

In batch it is setting X=ProcessID,3516 and blank space.
problem 1: for above code it is not displaying the value of X (in echo).
Problem 2: I want those %%i which is integer

Comment: [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: And in this example, you don't even need to set `%X%`; just echo `%%i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file variables initialized in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691047/batch-file-variables-initialized-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
set cmd="wmic process where (ProcessId=4192) get ParentProcessId"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%i IN ('%cmd%') DO ( 
    SET X=%%i 
    echo The process is !X!
)
pause
echo The process is %X%
EndLocal
pause
```

And why you don't use `Taskkill` command with param `/T` to terminates the specified process and any child processes which were started by it ?