# Batch File For loop not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to iterate over below loop , while executing if error occurs loop should go to IF condition and exit but loop never goes to IF condition always ELSE condition is executed , is there any problem with check of %errorlevel% ?

```
SET list=clean all cfg1 

CD "C:\SW\CONS\build"

FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (
    CALL build.bat %%a
    IF %errorlevel% neq 0 (
        echo Exiting the loop
        EXIT /B %errorlevel%
    ) ELSE  (
        echo Successfully executed "%%a"......
    )
)
```

Comment: you need to use delayed expansion and `!errorlevel!`

Comment: [Batch file variables initialized in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/691047/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Variables inside `(`parentheses`)` are expanded only once, so `%ERRORLEVEL%` will be replaced with whatever value it had when the `for` loop is parsed. You must either enable delayed expansion and use `!ERRORLEVEL!`, or just use `if errorlevel`:

```
for %%a in (%LIST%) do (
  call Build.bat %%a
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Exiting the loop
    goto :eof
  ) else (
    echo Successfully executed "%%a" . . .
  )
)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me , thank you