# Why does this cmd oneliner only work the second time it is called?

Tags: windows, cmd

Consider the following code executed on a Windows (10) cmd (this is actually a simplyfied version of a script that shows an erronous behavior):

```
type nul >> "a"
set "e=" & for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b a') do (set "e=%F" & if not defined e (echo "") else (echo "%e%"))
```

In short: reset the variable `e`, loop over files found by `dir`, make `e` the current filename, if `e` is defined, print it.

Run for the first time, it produces the output `%e%`. When executed a second time in the same shell, it produces `a` (which is what I would have expected). This doesn't happen when there is no `for` involved.

**What causes this behavior and how do I always get the correct output?**

Answer (score 2):

When CMD.EXE executes a line, it first replaces all variables with the current value **for the entire command line**. Then it executes the line. Because `e`isn't defined when the second command is executed, CMD doesn't remove `%e%`. The second time, the environment variable exists and gets replaced.

`%e%` is not a variable like in other languages that gets evaluated at the time the interpreter gets to the command.

If you change you sample script to

```
type nul >> "a"
set e=b
set "e=" & for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b a') do (set "e=%F" & if not defined e (echo "") else (echo "%e%"))
```

the output is `b` rather than `%e%` or `a` because that is the value of `e` at the time the line is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this seems to be the immediate expansion of variables by the `cmd`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/691127/275195) for a nicer description. According to [the cmd description (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), `cmd` contains a flag `/v:on` that allows **delayed variable expansion**. Above example then needs to become:

```
type nul >> "a"
set "e=" & for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b a') do (set "e=%F" & if not defined e (echo "") else (echo "!e!"))
```

This behavior is unexpected at least. The `cmd` is such a poor environment that it hurts me everytime I have to look at it.