# Replacing FIRST batch file from a CALLed SECOND batch file OK when its running?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, windows-xp

WinXP, Win7

FIRST.BAT Calls SECOND.BAT. 
Can SECOND.BAT safely replace FIRST.BAT?

FIRST.BAT:

```
@echo Hi, I need to be placed.
CALL SECOND.BAT
```

SECOND.BAT:

```
@echo Time to replace FIRST.BAT
copy /y NEWFIRST.BAT FIRST.BAT
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `CALL second.bat`.  Just use `SECOND.BAT`.  This way control is passed to second.bat and first.bat exits.

Comment: Ah, I wish I could... FIRST.BAT is already deployed on local machines.It Calls a common script on a networked location. I want to replace FIRST.BAT from that common SECOND.BAT script. Good idea, though...

Comment: Provided that the contents of the new `first.bat` are identical to the old contents up to and including the `call` command, yes, this will work.  (Technically even that isn't necessary, the contents don't need to be the same, the offset in the file just has to be correct.)

Comment: So push a new FIRST.bat to the computers using a GPO or put something in their logon script to redeploy it again.

Comment: @Harry I was afraid of that... was seeing if still applied in this instance. thx

Comment: @Squashman FIRST.BAT is the only startup control I have common to all these devices, so I'm searching for a method to replace FIRST.BAT with the limitations I have. Was hoping the fact that SECOND.BAt is CALLed by FIRST.BAT might buy me a pass, but alas not.

Comment: Shouldn't really be a problem.  Replace the original `first.bat` with an interim `first.bat` that is identical up to the `call` and then contains instructions to replace itself with the final version.  (The trick to that is to have the copy and a `goto` or `exit` command on the same line.)

Comment: Looks like I'll need to ensure NEWFIRST.BAT maintains the CALL offset in FIRST.BAT. I'm wondering how to accomplish that with an editor like UltraEdit or Notepad++... Hex mode to confirm?

Comment: "Don't use CALL second.bat. Just use SECOND.BAT" Hmmm... I wonder if I could replace CALL SECOND.BAT line with ____ SECOND.BAT (_=space)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Gents... Appreciate the extra brains on the problem.

Comment: This should explain what you need to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906586/changing-a-batch-file-when-its-running

Comment: Just a quick thought that I can't test right now. In second.bat, append a line to first.bat. **echo exit ^& copy newfirst.bat first.bat>>first.bat**

Comment: Put this in FIRST.BAT, all in same line: `@echo Hi, I need to be placed. & CALL SECOND.BAT & GOTO :EOF`. Then, you may replace it with whichever you want... If you need to put more lines/commands in FIRST.BAT, just enclose they all in parentheses including the `GOTO :EOF` at end.

Comment: @Aacini first.bat is local on all their computers. They can't change first.bat.