# Is there a way to create a persistent variable in batch file by writing to itself?

Tags: batch-file

I have written a batch file that I use for file management.  The batch file parses an .XML database to get a list of base filenames, then allows the user to move/copy those specific files into a new directory. The program prompts the user for a source directory and the name of the .XML file.  I would like the program to default the variables to the last used entry, even if the previous CMD session has closed.  My solution has been to ask the user for each variable at the beginning of the program, then write those variables to a separate batch file called param.bat at the end like this:

```
@echo off
set SOURCEDIR=NOT SET
set XMLFILE=NOT SET
if exist param.bat call param.bat
set /p SOURCEDIR=The current source directory is %SOURCEDIR%.  Please input new directory or press [Enter] for no change.
set /p XMLFILE=The current XML database is %XMLFILE%.  Please input new database or press [Enter] for no change.

REM {Rest of program goes here}

echo @echo off>param.bat
echo set SOURCEDIR=%SOURCEDIR%>>param.bat
echo set XMLFILE=%XMLFILE%>>param.bat
:END
```

I was hoping for a more elegant solution that does not require a separate batch file and allows me to store the variable data within the primary batch file itself.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you could store them in a file?

Comment: Take a look at [`setx`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html), which defines variables for *upcoming* sessions; you still need `set` to define them for the *current* session...

Comment: Although setx might work... setx is a bad idea.  EVERY single thing that runs will have all of those variables in the environment table.  The environment isn't meant to be a database.

Comment: Store the defaults in the registry.

Comment: You can create a variable and write it back to the batchfile itself and update it if needed.

Comment: @Laf well, that is what OP is doing already...

Comment: Try a look at [SO: Changing a batch file when its running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651656/463115)

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to save variables itself on the bat file, but, you need replace **:END** to **:EOF**

> [**:EOF have a good explained in this link**](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)   **.:|:.**   see [**Where does GOTO :EOF return to?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

Also, this work in **fat32/ntfs** file system!

You can write the variables in your bat file, and read when needs:

**Obs.:** Sorry my limited *English*

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "bat_file="%temp%\new_bat_with_new_var.tmp"" & type nul >!bat_file! & set "nop=ot Se"
for /f %%a in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo 0x40"') do set "delim=%%a"

type "%~f0"| findstr "!delim!"| find /v /i "echo" >nul || for %%s in (SOURCEDIR XMLFILE) do set "%%s=N!nop!t"
if defined SOURCEDIR echo/!SOURCEDIR!%delim%!XMLFILE!%delim%>>"%~f0" 

for /f "delims=%delim% tokens=1,2" %%a in ('type "%~f0"^| findstr /l "!delim!"^| find /v /i "echo"') do (

     set /p "SOURCEDIR=The current source directory is %%~a. Please input new directory or press [Enter] for no change: "
     set /p "XMLFILE=The current XML database is %%~b. Please input new database or press [Enter] for no change: "

     if /i "!old_string!" neq "!SOURCEDIR!!delim!!XMLFILE!!delim!" (

         type "%~f0"| findstr /vic:"%%~a!delim!%%~b!delim!">>!bat_file!"
         copy /y !bat_file! "%~f0" >nul

         echo/!SOURCEDIR!!delim!!XMLFILE!!delim!>>%~f0"
         goto :_continue_:

    ))

:_continue_:
rem :| Rest of program goes here | replace/change last command [goto :END] to [goto :EOF]

goto :EOF
rem :| Left 2 line blank above, because your variable will be save/read in next line above here |:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

dir /r "%~f0" | findstr /c:" %~nx0:settings" 2>nul >nul && (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~f0:settings") do set %%A
)

if defined SOURCEDIR echo The current source directory is %SOURCEDIR%.
set /p "SOURCEDIR= Please input new directory or press [Enter] for no change. "

if defined XMLFILE echo The current XML database is %XMLFILE%.
set /p "XMLFILE=Please input new database or press [Enter] for no change. "

(
    echo SOURCEDIR=%SOURCEDIR%
    echo XMLFILE=%XMLFILE%
) > "%~f0:settings"
```

This uses the Alternate Data Stream (ADS) of the batchfile to
save the settings.
NTFS file system is required. The ADS stream is lost if the
batchfile is copied to a file system other than NTFS.

The `dir` piped to `findstr` is to determine if the
stream does exist before trying to read from it.
This helps to avoid an error message from the `for`
loop if the ADS does not exist.

The `for` loop sets the variable names and values read from the ADS.

Finally, the variables are saved to the ADS.

**Note**:

- `%~f0` is full path to the batchfile.
  See `for /?` about all modifiers available.
- `%~f0:settings` is the batchfile with ADS named *settings*.
- `dir /r` displays files and those with ADS.

**Important**:

Any idea involving writing to the batchfile could result
in file corruption so would certainly advise a backup of
the batchfile.