# How to set a PATH to a batch file in windows

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd

In windows, I have two .bat files, say dir_a/a.bat, and dir_b/b.bat.

What I want is that after executing a.bat, I will be able to call b.bat. My approach now is to set a PATH to dir_b, so in a terminal that executed a.bat, I can just call b.bat and will be able to execute b.bat. Yet putting "set PATH=dir_b;%PATH%" in a.bat is not working. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For the case that you're dealing with a relative path:
You might notice that:

```
set path=%path%;"\..\..\..\vc98\bin\"
```

will ^^ **NOT work**  ^^ !

So do it like this:

```
pushd "..\..\..\vc98\bin\"
path %cd%; %path%
popd
```

...and of course a
**set path=%path%;%cd%**
between the pushd and popd will also do the trick

Well for also have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6595206/3135511

```
...
call :setAbsPath ABS_PATH ..\
...
```

^-To see to do it via the self made subfunction '**setAbsPath**'
-> or instead of **call** you may also use **For** - details in the other thread

---

> And just a small side note for those who might also like to run Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0(anno 1998) > without install it...
> ... and wonder where's that f*** 'standard' include ?!
>
> There are about 17 file in \vc98\include\ that  have been manually chopped 8 + 3 chars. Like:
> algrithm -> algorithm
> strstrem -> strstream
> xception -> exception
>
> So be aware and creative about that !

Answer (score 1):

You must include the *absolute* path to b.bat file; for example:

```
set PATH=C:\User A\Folder X\dir_b;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a `SETLOCAL` in `a.bat`. ANY environment changes made after a SETLOCAL are backed out when the matching `ENDLOCAL` (or `EOF` in the same context) is reached.

Depending on how you are terminating `a.bat`, you'd need something in the order of `ENDLOCAL&set "Path=dir_b;%PATH%"&GOTO :EOF` which will prepend `dir_b` to your existing path as you appear to exepect for the duration of that particular CMD session.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PATH because that conflicts with the Windows Path.  Instead you could add the following:

```
pushd path_to_your_dir_b
```

Then add popd in an appropriate place