# bash command to get the absolute path of a file: `%~dpnx1`

Tags: bash, path

i've seen this question:
[Get the absolute path of file in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642095/get-the-absolute-path-of-file-in-batch-script/20947521?noredirect=1#comment31466764_20947521)

And i was searching something pretty similar. The answer written there:

"You can use %~dpnx1. which expands to the drive, path, name and extension of the first argument. Don't forget to quote the name when passing it to another command, though."

is what i want to understand.
How should i use that command  `%~dpnx1` in my script to obtain the path of the own script is located? Or if someone know a simpler way is well accepted.

Thanks

Comment: On which operating system? Linux don't have "drives"....

Comment: You're tag says "bash" (implying Linux) but you are talking about a Windows batch mechanism. Can you give more detail on what you're trying to do?

Comment: oh right, i am trying to run a script on my Mac. And the first thing to do is to find the path of where my script is. I know that i could use the command find, but it's really slow. So i wanted to know if i could use that command or something equivalent that find me the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to find your bash script's absolute path while the script itself is running:

```
dir=$( cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P )
```

Comment: perfect. I used this solution and work for me. Thanks