# Get absolute path of a file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Java application that produces an output which is stored in a `myfile.txt` file using batch script. Now I would like to pass the absolute path of this `myfile.txt` file to another java application as a command line argument.

So something like:

```
java -jar "path/to/jar/MyJar.jar" > myfile.txt

<Something to get and store absolute path of myfile.txt>

java -jar "path/to/jar/MyOtherJar.jar" <absolute path of myfile.txt>
```

Now I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642095/get-the-absolute-path-of-file-in-batch-script) which states the use of `%~dpnx1` but I can't understand how to apply this. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are creating a file in current directory then you can use $PWD to get the current direct path. Then you just have to concatenate file name with that.

Comment: The `MyOtherJar` file is in a separate directory. It is not in the same directory as `myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the `%~dpnx1` or simply `%~f1` syntax requires that the filename is in the arguments.
dpnx=(D)rive (P)ath (N)ame e(X)tension = Full(F)ilename

That can be done via `CALL :func <argument>` or via `FOR`.

```
call :getAbsolutePath resultVar "myFile.txt"
echo %resultVar%
exit /b


:getAbsolutePath <returnVar> <filename>
set "%1=%~f2"
exit /b
```

Or via `FOR`

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%X in ("myFile.txt") DO set "absPath=%%~fX"
```

Comment: This works fine. Can you please tell me what is the use of `%%~fX` here? Also, is there any way I can avoid generating this `myfile.txt` and directly pass the output of `MyJar` to `MyOtherJar`? I was doing it this way because I am not very familiar with the syntax. If there is a way of eliminating this extra file generation step?

Comment: `%%~fX` uses the `FOR` parameter `%%X` with the modifier `~f` to get the absolute filename.

Comment: @jackw To avoid your temporary file, probably a pipe could work `java -jar "path/to/jar/MyJar.jar" | java -jar "path/to/jar/MyOtherJar.jar"` but if it works depends on the jar files

Comment: Why are you using a `for /F` loop although a standard `for` loop would suffice?

Comment: @aschipfl There is no explicit reason, it's only a habit