# CMD Windows find/search and return absolute path

Tags: cmd

is there a way to return absolute path of a file and or folder by find?

let's say filename.txt in C:\test

```
set file=filename.txt

dir %file% /s
```

at now it return c:\test in line 6. but what i want is it return absolute path

c:\test\filename.txt and set it to variabel to be use next time.

thank you

Comment: `dir /S /B` returns full paths...

Comment: @aschipfl thx its that i want. by the way do you know how pass the value from dir to next command in 1 line? at now i try `dir filename /s /b | del` i dont know how to bypass the return to del.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `/B` option to the [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)`/S` command line, so it returns full absolute paths.

To capture the output of this command line, use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /S /B "filename.txt"') do rem/ Do something with `%I`...
```

For example, to delete matching files, do this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /S /B "filename.txt"') do del "%I"
```

Note that you have to double the `%` signs for this code to be used within a batch file, so `%I` becomes `%%I`!

Comment: Cool thats i want. now i try to infinite loop. i get error in for /f delims with basic loop `:loop and goto loop` how i can achieve this without hungry resource?

Comment: @ aschipfl sory if i  interrupt u. how can i get 1 down folder from absolute path? lets say C:\test\boo\filename.txt. i want to get C:\test\boo\ only. so far i try is with find str but like something wrong.`
set file = filename 

`for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /S /B %file&') do findstr,%file%,, "%%I"`

from above code  i inialize filename to variabel file and using findstr to replace with 3 argument. 1. filename. 2. change to empty. 3. output from dir. to use later with rmdir. thx

Comment: To point to the parent directory of an item, simply append `\..` (like `%I\..` in my code); to resolve it (so to change `C:\test\boo\filename.txt\..` to `C:\test\boo`) use a standard `for` loop (no `/F`): `for %J in ("C:\test\boo\filename.txt\..") do echo/%~J`, or `for %J in ("%I\..") do echo/%~J` in my code...

Comment: Sorry, for me this is answer does not really help: dir /s actually searches the whole harddrive (below the cwd) for files with the same name and finally outputs all them with their absolute path.
This:
- does not convert a single file path but could output several paths
- takes soo long

Comment: @ChrisFetz, to search in the current working directory, just use `dir /B` without `/S`: `for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /B "filename.txt"') do set "FILE=%~fI"`…

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get the filename as a first argument to a batch script, your batch-script could look like this:

```
set file=%~dpnx1
echo %file%
```

Calling the script will return the the absolute path to the given file and you may use it as a variable onwards.
More details on this can be found in the post: [Resolve absolute path from relative path and/or file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645843/resolve-absolute-path-from-relative-path-and-or-file-name)

Comment: Why don't you like `%~f1`? ;-)

Comment: i get the answer from previous answer. i don't know why he delete his answer. its just a simple options that i dont mention in dir. /b