# Normalize file path in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way to resolve the `..` from an absolute file path in batch? For example, the following batch script should output `C:\Users\xyz\other\abc.txt`:

```
REM Project dir is an absolute path, for example, C:\Users\xyz\project\
SET projectDir=%~1

REM Target file is a path relative to the project dir, for example, ..\other\abc.txt
SET target=%~2

REM Concatenate paths. This becomes C:\Users\xyz\project\..\other\abc.txt
SET absoluteTarget=%projectDir%%target%
SET absoluteTargetClean=...
echo %absoluteTargetClean%
```

The `absoluteTarget` variable refers to an existing file.

I need the same for a directory instead of the file. Can you use the same way to achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404867/2029097

Comment: That's not what I'd call an absolute path, I'd call it a relative path! I suppose you should clarify whether or not the file path given exists on the end users system. _(If it doesn't, i.e. is just a string, the answer may be completely different!)_

Comment: @Compo I thought the difference between a relative and an absolute path is the following: Relative paths start from the working directory, absolute paths start from the file system root. My path is absolute since it starts with `C:`. I think what you mean is called _normalized path_.

Comment: Surely all you need to do is in the example you've given is remove the "\project\.." from the path?

Comment: @SPlatten The paths come from the command line arguments, so I cant just replace the string. I edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: I recommend using `%~1` and `%~2` to remove eventually surrounding quotes (quotes are needed to give a path or file name with spaces as *one* argument).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wonder, how anyone ever could come up with a path like `C:\Users\xyz\project\..\other\abc.txt`, but here we go:

```
SET "absPath=C:\Users\xyz\project\..\other\abc.txt"
for %%i in ("%absPath%") do SET "absPathClean=%%~fi"
echo %absPathClean%
```

works for both files and folders.

For more information, consult `for /?`

Comment: I edited the question and added that the path is built from command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the example values from my question. Is there a similar method for relative paths? For example, the path `data\..\..\other\abc.txt` should be transformed to `..\other\abc.txt`.

Comment: no, this always generates, what you called a "normalized path"