# Strip drive letter

Tags: batch-file

By using the command from a folder in D: drive

```
for /f "delims="  %%d in ('cd') do set pathdrv=%%d

echo %pathdrv%
```

I get "d:\some folder".I want to write batch commands to create autorun file in the root of the drive. Please help me to strip the drive letter "d:" so the output is "\some folder" and what extra change do i do to strip "\".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: Use the substring syntax to strip the first two characters from the `%cd%` pseudo-variable:

```
%cd:~2%
```

To remove the first backslash too:

```
%cd:~3%
```

This reliably works even with Unicode paths when the console window is set to raster fonts.

---

Longer answer, detailing some more options (none of which work well enough):

For arguments to the batch file you can use the special syntax `%p1`, which gives you the path of the first argument given to a batch file (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/underused-features-of-windows-batch-files/534767#534767)).

This doesn't work the same way with environment variables but there are two tricks you can employ:

1. Use a subroutine:

   ```
   call :foo "%cd%"
   ...
   goto :eof
   :foo
   set result=%~p1
   goto :eof
   ```

   Subroutines can have arguments, just like batch files.
2. Use `for`:

   ```
   for %%d in ("%cd%") do set mypath=%%~pd
   ```

However, both variants *don't* work when

- The console is set to "Raster fonts" instead of a TrueType font such as Lucida Console or Consolas.
- The current directory contains Unicode characters

  - That have no representation in the current legacy codepage (for Western cultures, CJK is a good choice that doesn't fit). Remember that in this case you'll only get question marks instead of the characters.

The problem with this is that whil environment variables can *hold* Unicode just fine you'll get into problems once you try setting up a command line which *sets* them. Every option detailed above relies on output of some kind before the commands are executed. This has the problem that Unicode isn't preserved but replaced by `?`. The only exception is the substring variant at the very start of this answer which retains Unicode characters in the path even with raster fonts.

Comment: Hm, sorry. I got a little carried away when expanding on your answer. That the actual answer is now a completely different one is an unfortunate side-effect of my research during writing. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 6):

Drive letter:

```
%CD:~0,1%
```

Full drive name (incl. colon):

```
%CD:~0,2%
```