# Script to automate URL opening in multiple tabs in Firefox or Opera from a text file

Tags: firefox, scripting, opera

I have a text file with lots of links-each line has a link (i.e the separator is '\n'). i want to write a script so that each link opens in a different tab in Firefox or Internet explorer. How can I do this? I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Question could be clarified a little bit: do you want to keep the list in a plain text format so that you can easily edit it, or do you want to just convert it as-is to a script?

Comment: @hallvors:yes, the list is in plain text format only

Comment: so you would rather not convert it to a batch file per instructions below? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a text file called whatever.bat and put it on your desktop. edit the file and enter:

```
set "fileList="
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%i IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\mdevine\Desktop\urls.txt") DO call set "fileList=%%fileList%% %%i"
start firefox %fileList%
```

close and save

double click on it

Note: C:\Documents and Settings\mdevine\Desktop\urls.txt is a text file that contains the following:

```
http://www.rte.ie
http://www.python.org
http://www.bbc.co.uk
http://www.google.com
```

Comment: each line of the txt file has a link ..so the separator is not a space

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked for me is:

```
set "fileList="
FOR /F "usebackq delims=," %%i IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\xwell\Desktop\urls.txt") DO (
start %%i
)
```

Four changes I made:

1. I set the delimiter to a comma - *delims=,*
2. Put a comma between each URL in my text file
3. And put the for loop function in brackets
4. Changed the start function. This uses the default browser, though you could specify it as per the above example

So, the text file *urls.txt* looks like:

```
http://www.rte.ie,
http://www.python.org,
http://www.bbc.co.uk,
http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

@iceman, @amadain:

refining @amadains solution: 
the "[line continuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395?tab=votes#tab-top)" in batch files is ^, so iceman should change his text files accordingly (add a ^ at the end of each line) and put "start firefox ^" at the beginning of the file . Don't know max length of command line string, though.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for how to do this in Chrome, here is the solution :

```
@echo off

set URL1= https://www.google.com
set URL2= https://www.youtube.com
set URL3= https://stackoverflow.com

start chrome --new-window "%URL1%" "%URL2%" "%URL3%"
```

Save this code as batch file and just double click.

Note that there is no space before the = sign
It wasn't working for me when i tried with space