# Is it possible to create chrome shortcut to open set of URLs in different tabs in same window?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs

Is there any way to create a shortcut that opens a set of URLs in different tabs in the same browser window in Chrome browser? Similarly i want another shortcut so that i want to open another set of URL in another separate chrome window in separate tabs

EDIT :

I got the perfect solution

Create a batch file with below code :-

```
@echo off

start chrome --new-window "url1" "url2" "url3"
```

Comment: You can refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752133/script-to-automate-url-opening-in-multiple-tabs-in-firefox-or-opera-from-a-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with this solution :

```
@echo off

set URL1= https://www.google.com
set URL2= https://www.youtube.com
set URL3= https://stackoverflow.com

start chrome --new-window "%URL1%" "%URL2%" "%URL3%"
```

Save this code as batch file and just double click.

Note that there is no space before the = sign It wasn't working for me when i tried with space

Answer (score -1):

Use bookmark feature in chrome, which will create shortcut for you to access it directly.

Goto more option in top right corner then find bookmark in  the list

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't what i was looking for. I wanted to open a set of urls simultaneously ss different tabs in same browser window. I got a solution. Will post it below