# What useful developer tools does Windows XP come with?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I work in a pseudo-IT team that does development outside of a formal IT development environment - using Windows XP (and IE6). I can't install any software myself, so can only use what the central IT department makes available - which isn't much.

I have lots of UNIX development experience, so it's painful working without some of the tools I have previously taken for granted.

Notepad is my favorite thing about Windows. What else is there hiding in C:\Windows that I should know about?

Comment: [Dr. Watson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/14/492483.aspx)!

Answer (score 2):

Not a great deal, if you're used to the plethora that comes with UNIX. The `cmd.exe` language has come a long way since the brain-dead version with MS-DOS. It's still no match for `bash` but it's not bad. Check out [Rob Van der Woude's site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/) ("Batch Files" link on the left side) for some fantastic little snippets.

I do know that `findstr` now does regular expressions so it's at least coming close to `grep`.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/underused-features-of-windows-batch-files) (which has a couple of answers from me and absolute bucketloads from everyone else) re Windows batch files.

Comment: Except that, for doing anything "serious", you must use some incredible trickery that will inevitably include a weird `for` with a ton of incomprehensible options.

Comment: @Matteo: yes but, as they say, if the only tool you have is a piece of wet celery, every problem looks like a ... well ... I can't actually think of anything funny to say here :-) OP stated that they were only allowed to use standard tooling so that's how I answered.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: That's why I mentioned `cscript` in my answer. JavaScript may not be the world's best programming language, but it sure beats `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

- A JavaScript interpreter: `cscript` / `wscript` (can also interpret VBScript plus any other language for which a Windows ScriptingHost compliant interpreter is installed)
- WordPad: practically useless except for one thing: it can read Unix line endings, unlike NotePad
- if you're lucky: PowerShell

Note that plenty of applications are also packaged as so-called *portable* applications which need no installation: Firefox, NotePad++, even a complete Ubuntu distribution.

Answer (score 0):

`ntsd` (the Windows NT debugger for user-mode programs - command line stuff, a bit like `gdb`) was available by default on Windows installations in the `system32` directory, although I think that this policy has changed since I can't find it in my Windows 7 64 bit installation.

Answer (score 0):

mmm... not much indeed, besides I think everything that comes out of the box have already been mentioned...

not really answering your question, but I would recommend to use [portable software](http://portableapps.com/), there's a huge collection of them available, like notepad++, winmerge, grepwin...