# Redirecting keyboard input+text+error text to nul with 2>&1 in CMD

Tags: cmd, redirect, nul

I need to redirect keyboard input + text + error text in CMD to nul with maximum 2 expressions.
Something like `*command* >nul 2>&1`.

An alternative is `>nul 1>nul 2>nul` but as I said, I want to reduce the command as much as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way of redirects all 3 (`stdin`, `stdout` & `stderr`) to `nul` in any less than 3 commands.

So, if that is acceptable - Similar to  [Hidden features of Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/hidden-features-of-windows-batch-files/246691#246691) - `command <nul >nul 2>&1`, which redirects `stdout` to nul, and `stderr` to the same place as `stdout`

0 = `stdin`
1 [Default is omitted like in example] = `stdout`
2 = `stderr`