# How to workaround doskey's special character, like $L

Tags: cmd, doskey

I got a useful tip from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/374363/151453 , but plagued by doskey's special characters.

(env: Windows 7 and Windows XP)

Using Visual C++ command line, we have env-vars `INCLUDE` and `LIB`. So with this doskey macro,

```
doskey whichinclude=for %i in ($1) do @echo.%~$INCLUDE:i
```

we can easily findout which .h is found first in which INCLUDE directory, really convenient.

[image]

However, this trick fails for `LIB`. **I just CANNOT simply code a macro like:**

```
doskey whichlib=for %i in ($1) do @echo.%~$LIB:i
```

Call `whichlib winsock32.lib`, it spouts `The system cannot find the file specified.`

[image]

I launch Procmon to know what happens, it reveals:

[image]

So I realize `$L` has special meaning for `doskey`, it is replaced with current drive letter when run.

Try double dollar( `@echo.%~$$LIB:i` ), still not working, Procmon report CMD accessing `C:\echo` .

Counld someone kindly help me out?

My doskey book mark: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Instead of trying to get it to work as a doskey alias, just make it a `whichlib.cmd` one-liner batch file: `@for %%i in (%1) do @if NOT "%%~$LIB:i"=="" @echo %%~$LIB:i`

Comment: And just for future reference, I think that most people would prefer if copy-paste snippets from console sessions were done as text instead of images. Formatting the text as code usually works pretty well.

Comment: Well, I got your idea. I use screen shots to manifest that I'm not asking my questing by just conceiving, and screen shot can avoid accidental copy paste error, finally it is visually attracting.

Comment: I'm not sure why copy/paste from a console window would be any more error prone than pasting a screen shot, text is generally easier to read than screen shots (particularly for readers who might have vision problems), and like I said, sometimes pasting the example into an editor allows for additional analysis or testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Michael Burr's comment - you may be better off with a batch file. I generally do not use DOSKEY macros because they do not work within batch files, so it seems kind of pointless. In my mind, if a command works on the command line, it should also work within a batch file.

But... it is possible to do what you want :)

The `$` only has special meaning if it is followed by a character that has special meaning to DOSKEY. The `$L` is interpreted as the `<` character (input redirection). The MS documentation implies that `$$L` should give a `$L` literal, but the documentation is not correct, as you have discovered.

The DOSKEY $ substitution happens before the normal command line parsing. The trick to embed a literal `$L` in your macro definition is to put an intervening character between `$` and `L` that is not treated as special by DOSKEY, but that disappears during the normal command line parsing - The `^` works perfectly. `$^` has no special meaning to DOSKEY, and `^L` simply becomes `L` during command line parsing.

You can list the definition of your DOSKEY macros by using `DOSKEY /M`.

The full definition you require is `whichlib=for %i in ($1) do @echo(%~$^LIB:i`.

The `^` must be escaped when you define the macro. So the complete line to define the macro becomes:

```
doskey whichlib=for %i in ($1) do @echo(%~$^^LIB:i
```

Comment: Very good answer and explanation, verified! I used to load my doskey macros with CMD command ``doskey /macrofile=F:\ChjConfigs\chjmacro.txt`` , now I write in chjmacro.txt ``whichlib=for %i in ($1) do @echo %~$^LIB:i``, working like a charm.

Comment: Of course, better add a dot after ``echo``, i.e. ``whichlib=for %i in ($1) do @echo.%~$^LIB:i`` , so that when no matching file is found, ``echo`` displays nothing instead of mumbling ``ECHO is on.`` .

Comment: @JimmChen - I know it looks wrong, but ECHO( is the only totally reliable variant. ECHO. can fail in some obscure scenarios.