# How to separate line in two within a Batch file (DOS)?

Tags: batch-file

In bash (Linux), if I have a very big command that is way large for only one line, I can use a backslash character to separate it:

```
./call-something.sh && \
./call-other-thing.sh
```

How can I do this in a BAT file (Windows)? I've tried with a backslash too and I get:

```
"\" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>^</kbd> as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245434/1046267).

For easy reference, I include the example given in the linked answer:

```
call C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntbackup.exe ^
    backup ^
    /V:yes ^
    /R:no ^
    /RS:no ^
    /HC:off ^
    /M normal ^
    /L:s ^
    @daily.bks ^
    /F daily.bkf
```

Comment: @knocte, Click [here for a better reference that explains the rules for line continuation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4455750/1012053)