# Order in which command prompt executes files with the same name (a.bat vs a.cmd vs a.exe)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, batch-file

What is the order in which the Windows command prompt executes files with the same name, but different extensions?

For example, I have a bunch of executable files: `something.cmd`, `something.bat` and `something.exe`. Which of these would be executed when I typed `something` into a command prompt (given they were on the path, etc.)? If that file did not exist which one would then be executed?

Is there a reference that describes this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay, I did some quick experimentation based on some other searches I had going.

The gist is that the order of the commands is dependent on the order the extensions are stored in the `PATHEXT` environment variable. So initially I had:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.RB;.RBW
```

and for the example above the order in which it would run it was:

```
something.exe
something.bat
something.cmd
```

Changing the order which they were defined in the `PATHEXT` environment variable did indeed change the order in which they were executed.

Comment: If the `PATHEXT` variable is deleted, the order is the same as in the old MS-DOS days: COM, EXE, BAT and now CMD.