# How to execute a .bat file first instead of an file .exe when both have the same path/name?

Tags: windows, emacs, batch-file, cmd

My `emacs.bat` rest in the same bin directory as `emacs.exe`. This directory is included in the PATH variable (Windows).

Content of `emacs.bat`:

```
@echo off "%~dp0emacsclientw.exe" -na "%~dp0runemacs.exe" "%1"
```

However, whenever I use this command, `emacs.exe` gets executed instead of the .bat file. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you could put the emacs.bat in another directory and place that directory earlier in the PATH. Note: if you were to run "emacs" while in the directory containing emacs.exe then the .exe would take precedence.

*<strike>Edit: Alternatively, you could just type `emacs.bat` instead of `emacs` at the command prompt.</strike>*

*Edit 2: As seen in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605101/order-in-which-command-prompt-executes-files-with-the-same-name-a-bat-vs-a-cmd#answer-605139), you could set the `PATHEXT` environment variable. Something along the lines of:*

`PATHEXT=.BAT;.COM;.EXE;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.RB;.RBW`

Comment: I have to modify .bat a little but it works like a charm. Simple solution indeed. Thanks,

Comment: You're welcome, @user1970791. Note "Edit 2" that I put in my Answer after you accepted it. That might be a better solution for you.