# why typing "mymodule" executes "mymodule.py"

Tags: python, windows

On my Windows 10 machine, I had written a script called `ffmpeg.py` that wrapped features of `ffmpeg`. I noticed that when I call `ffmpeg` in a CMD console it calls my script instead (which can be convenient, well you have to be aware of that).

On another configuration (windows server 2008) at work, I have to specify the `.py` extension explicitly.

Any explanation? And how the command prompt knows how to add the `.py` extension like it knows how to add the `.exe`, `.bat`, ... extension? Registry key?

Comment: cmd.exe searches for the name as given and also with each of the extensions listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. You should answer instead of commenting!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605101/205580).