# Check for null variable in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm working on a Windows batch file that will bcp three text files into SQL Server. If something goes wrong in production, I want to be able to override the file names. So I'm thinking of doing something like this.

```
bcp.exe MyDB..MyTable1 in %1 -SMyServer -T -c -m0
bcp.exe MyDB..MyTable2 in %2 -SMyServer -T -c -m0
bcp.exe MyDB..MyTable3 in %3 -SMyServer -T -c -m0
```

I would like to be able to enter default names for all three files, to be used if the positional parameters are not supplied. The idea would be either to execute

```
myjob.bat
```

with no parameters, and have it use the defaults, or execute

```
myjob.bat "c:\myfile1" "c:\myfile2" "c:\myfile3"
```

and have it use those files. I haven't been able to figure out how to tell if %1, %2 and %3 exist and/or are null. I also don't know how to set those values conditionally. Is this possible? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone interested in implementing optional script parameters with default values should have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053) to a question about [Windows Bat file optional argument parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3973824/1012053)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

To test for the existence of a command line parameter, use empty brackets:

```
IF [%1]==[] echo Value Missing
```

or

```
IF [%1] EQU [] echo Value Missing
```

The [SS64 page on IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) will help you here, under "Test if a variable is empty".

You can't set a positional parameter, so what you should do is do something like

```
SET MYVAR=%1
```

You can then re-set MYVAR based on its contents.

Comment: Does this mean `IF "%1"==""` is bad?

Comment: Yes "%1" generates syntax error when arg1 has a quotes, so better to use square brackets.

Comment: `IF "%~1" == ""` is nearly always the best option, don't use `IF [%1]==[]`, because it fails with content like `file with space.txt`, `Special&char`

Answer (score 29):

The right thing would be to use a "if defined" statement, which is used to test for the existence of a variable. For example:

```
IF DEFINED somevariable echo Value exists
```

In this particular case, the negative form should be used:

```
IF NOT DEFINED somevariable echo Value missing
```

**PS: the variable name should be used without "%" caracters.**

Comment: thanks for the answer. Would that work with numbered parameters, like I'm using in my example, or only with named variables?

Comment: +1 because this works also if `somevariable` has **quotes** while `IF [%somevariable%]==[]` throw one error.

Comment: @TerraAshley because this doesn't work unfortunately with %1

Answer (score 28):

Both answers given are correct, but I do mine a little different.  You might want to consider a couple things...

Start the batch with:

```
SetLocal
```

and end it with

```
EndLocal
```

This will keep all your 'SETs" to be only valid during the current session, and will not leave vars left around named like "FileName1" or any other variables you set during the run, that could interfere with the next run of the batch file.  So, you can do something like:

```
IF "%1"=="" SET FileName1=c:\file1.txt
```

The other trick is if you only provide 1, or 2 parameters, use the SHIFT command to move them, so the one you are looking for is ALWAYS at %1...

For example, process the first parameter, shift them, and then do it again.  This way, you are not hard-coding %1, %2, %3, etc...

The Windows batch processor is *much* more powerful than people give it credit for..  I've done some crazy stuff with it, including calculating yesterday's date, even across month and year boundaries including Leap Year, and localization, etc.

If you really want to get creative, you can call functions in the batch processor...  But that's really for a different discussion...  :)

Oh, and don't name your batch files **.bat** either..  They are **.cmd**'s now..  heh..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Just curious... Why .cmd instead of .bat?

Comment: Actually, I think this is a throw-back.  BAT is for DOS, and CMD is for WinNT..  But, the real reason is, at one time, you had cmd.exe, and command.com.  .cmd was related to cmd.exe, it was the parser for those.  I think it also makes you look cooler, but I can't confirm that.  :)

Comment: There is a subtle difference between them, and Raymond Chen had an Old New Thing post about it that I can't find right now... Google is not being my friend. See also this SO Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd

Answer (score 13):

```
rem set defaults:
set filename1="c:\file1.txt"
set filename2="c:\file2.txt"
set filename3="c:\file3.txt"
rem set parameters:
IF NOT "a%1"=="a" (set filename1="%1")
IF NOT "a%2"=="a" (set filename2="%2")
IF NOT "a%3"=="a" (set filename1="%3")
echo %filename1%, %filename2%, %filename3%
```

Be careful with quotation characters though, you may or may not need them in your variables.

Comment: +1; Almost any character or string will do: if not %1.==.; if not {%1}=={}; if not %1null==null...

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but currently the accepted one is at least suboptimal.

Using quotes is ALWAYS better than using any other characters to enclose `%1`.
Because when `%1` contains spaces or special characters like `&`, the `IF [%1] ==` simply stops with a syntax error.

But for the case that `%1` contains quotes, like in `myBatch.bat "my file.txt"`, a simple `IF "%1" == ""` would fail.

But as you can't know if quotes are used or not, there is the syntax `%~1`, this removes enclosing quotes when necessary.

Therefore, the code should look like

```
set "file1=%~1"
IF "%~1"=="" set "file1=default file"

type "%file1%"   --- always enclose your variables in quotes
```

If you have to handle stranger and nastier arguments like `myBatch.bat "This & will "^&crash`
Then take a look at [SO:How to receive even the strangest command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4200316/463115)