# Passing parameter with double quotes in cmd

Tags: parameters, cmd

So I ran into following issue. I need to run some program with parameters from cmd and one of parameters has double quotes symbol in it, e.g. `Some parameter "" with double quotes`. So how to pass it? I tried `"Some parameter ^"^" with double quotes"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try backslash '\' before the double quotes like "abcd\"\"efg"

Comment: @AndreiShakh, it will *not work* in batch files, but the OP is trying to pass a quoted string containing double quotes to a program *from* cmd. In this case the proposed solution *should* work (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23774994/2861476))