# Im passing a multi line text as argument which will be saved in a variable and then the file created has only 1 Lline

Tags: batch-file

```
Set a=%~1
echo %a%>>"C:\file.txt"
```

Im calling the script via cmd
"C:\batch.bat" "$Multi Line String$"

The output file is only having the text till the first line break.
Please Help

Comment: How do you specify the multi-line string? Please provide an example!

Comment: @abelenky: It is very simple: `set LF=^` & `%Two empty%` & `%lines%` & `set "var=Line one!LF!Line two!LF!Line three"`, but it is not common... @RameshEol: perhaps `echo !a!` do the trick (it works here).

Comment: There is no way to pass a value with multi-line text _in a Batch file parameter_. You should pass _the name_ of the multi-line text variable instead and expand it using DelayedExpansion this way: `Set a=%~1` & `echo !%a%!>>"C:\file.txt"`

Comment: echo !a!>>"C:\file.txt" dint work

Comment: im passing the multi line string from another application. It is a field which is having multi line text. Something like. 
Line1: Test. 
Line2: Testing. 
Line3: Tested.

Comment: I am only getting Line1: Test
in my output file file.txt

Comment: I didn't said `echo !a!`, but `echo !%a%!` or simpler: `echo !%~1!`, but both forms require `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. Is the "another application" a Batch file? Are you sure that the value is in an _environment variable_? Please, show the code of the other application that calls this Batch file!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, there is a way to to pass a value with multi-line text in a Batch file parameter.
But it is a little bit complex and currently there isn't a way to get the content out of the parameter in a safe way for any possible content.

A simple demonstration

Producer.bat - puts `"Line1<line feed>Line2"` into `%1`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=empty=%
)
set ^"pVar=^^^^^"Line1^^^^!LF!!LF!line2""
call Receiver.bat %%pVar%% #
```

Receiver.bat

```
@echo off
prompt :
@echo on
(
@exit /b
REM # %~1 #
)
```

Output

> :(
>
> REM # Line1
>    line2 #
>   )

To fetch this, the solution from [How to receive even the strangest command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4200316/463115) can be extended.

The problem is, that it only works with simple content, but there exists content which can't be received without producing parser errors.
Like: `"Line1<line feed>Line2"`

Therefore I would recommend [Aacini's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879148/463115)

**Edit: Improved samples**

A batch file to call another batch file with multi line variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=empty=%
)

set "var=Line1!\n!line2!\n!line3!\n!line4"
call :callBatch var
exit /b


:callBatch
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "prepVar=!%~1!"
for %%L in ("!\n!") DO (
    for %%b in ("^=^^" "&=^&" "<=^<" ">=^>" "|=^|") do set "prepVar=!prepVar:%%~b!"
    set "prepVar=^^"!prepVar:%%~L=^^%%~L%%~L!""
)
rem echo !prepVar!-
call receiver.bat %%prepVar%%
exit /b
```

And a receiver.bat that accepts and parses a multi line value from `%1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
prompt :
(
    @echo on
    for %%a in (4) do (
        @goto :next
        rem # %~1#
    )
) > param.tmp
:next
@echo off
endlocal
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set lineNo=0
(
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%L in (param.tmp) do (
    set /a lineNo+=1
    set "line=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if !lineNo! EQU 1 (
        set "line=!line:*# =!"
        set "line=!line:~,-2!"
    ) ELSE IF "!line!"==") " (
        goto :exit
    ) ELSE (
        set "line=!line:* =!"
        set "line=!line:~,-1!"
    )
    (echo(!line!)
    endlocal
)
) > file.txt
:exit

type file.txt
```

**Edit2: Unsolved problems**
It's possible to fetch any content in line1, but all other lines have restrictions for their content.
The content has to be "parse conform", that means that a multi line parameter with this content fails

> Line1
>   If a=

It's because the first line can be secured with `REM`, but all other lines have to be valid lines.
Carets are only visible in line1 (with the REM technic).
And lines beginning with `@` are empty and `:` are removed completly.

Comment: Ok! IMHO the academic discussion of abstract points is right in DosTips, but in this site you should post working solutions! **`;)`**. Two points: **1.** You forgot a right parenthesis in this line: `> file.txt`. **2.** Your method does not manage special Batch characters. I added my own solution based on your new method, please review it...

Comment: @Aacini Thanks I fixed the two points and add the description of the unsolved problems

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment, there is no way to pass a value with multi-line text *in a Batch file parameter*. You should pass *the name* of the multi-line text variable instead and expand it using DelayedExpansion. This is an example of such a method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a variable with just LineFeed
set LF=^
%Don't remove%
%these two lines%

rem Create the variable with multi-line text
set "MultiLineString=Line1: Test.!LF!Line2: Testing.!LF!Line3: Tested."

rem Call the Batch script passing *THE NAME* of the variable
cmd /C batch.bat MultiLineString
```

And this is your same **batch.bat** script with the changes I suggested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set a=%~1
echo !%a%!> file.txt

echo File created:
type file.txt
```

Output:

```
File created:
Line1: Test.
Line2: Testing.
Line3: Tested.
```

This method works as long as the calling program have stored the multi-line string *in an environment variable*, that is the only type of variables that can be accessed by a Batch file. For this reason, it is important for us to know how you created the multi-line string; otherwise, we have no means to solve this problem...

**EDIT**: *New method added*

After I read the improvements to [jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880266/778560) I must admit that I was wrong: it is possible to pass the value of a multi-line variable in a Batch file parameter. This is my own version of such a method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a variable with just LineFeed
(set LF=^
%empty line%
)

rem Create the variable with multi-line text
set "MultiLineString=Line1: <Test>.!LF!Line2: |Testing|.!LF!Line3: &Tested&."

rem Prepare the multi-line variable and call the receiver Batch file
call :callBatch
echo Back to caller...
goto :EOF


:callBatch

rem Prepare the multi-line variable
set "lines="
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!MultiLineString!") do (
   if not defined lines (
      set "lines=%%a "
   ) else (
      set "line=%%a"
      for %%b in ("&=^&" "<=^<" ">=^>" "|=^|") do set "line=!line:%%~b!"
      set "lines=!lines!!LF!!line!"
   )
)
REM echo [!lines!]

rem Call the receiver Batch file
(batch.bat "!lines!")
exit /B
```

And this is the new version of the companion **batch.bat** file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
   prompt $S
   echo on
   for %%a in (_) do if a==b (
      %1
   )
) > param.tmp

@echo off
(for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%a in (param.tmp) do if "%%a" neq ")" (
   set "line=%%a"
   echo(!line:~1,-2!
)) > file.txt
del param.tmp

echo File created:
echo/
type file.txt
```

This version correctly manage most special Batch characters, excepting exclamation-mark. This is the output:

```
File created:

Line1: <Test>.
Line2: |Testing|.
Line3: &Tested&.

Back to caller...
```

PS - This method will not work if the receiver **batch.bat** file is executed from outside another batch file, that is, via the standard `cmd /C batch.bat "$Multi Line String$"` method.

Comment: There is always a way, see my answer :-) But your solution is still bettter

Comment: I appended a "full solution", please review it

Comment: Your solution uses the simpler `if a==b` construct, and your escaping for special characters is good but the caret is missing `"^=^^"`. The main problem still stands, your version can't get carets at all `Line1 ^ caret!LF!Line2 ^ caret` (Mine gets only the caret in line1). And the main problem is that our code fails always for `Line1!LF!if diff piff`