# Command redirection in macros returns syntax error

Tags: batch-file

I am working on [batch-macro style](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1827) invented by **@jeb**, **@dbenham** and DosTips user **@Ed Dyreen**. The macro safely echoes `%1` to a file, and uses `SET /P` to extract & set the variable. [Full script](https://pastebin.com/8nYQBMjE)

However, the line

```
>args.tmp FOR %%? in (%%?) do REM .
```

returns syntax error

> `FOR %%? in` was unexpected at this time

However, I can't put the whole command in parenthesis, because the last line was designed to "catch" the arguments, like this:

```
%$MACRO.GetArgs% COMMAND_LINE_ARGS
```

which will expand to:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & >args.tmp FOR %%? in (%%?) do REM . COMMAND_LINE_ARGS_THAT_CAN_BE_SAFELY_PROCESSED
```

Therefore, this is **impractical**:

```
>args.tmp (
FOR %%? in (%%?) do REM .
)
```

**Summary: Are there other ways to redirect command output to a file?**
Sources:

- [How to receive even the strangest command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200316/how-to-receive-even-the-strangest-command-line-parameters)
- https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518
- https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=13002#p13002
- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html

Comment: @SomethingDark In `for %%a in (something) do echo %1` , if `%1` is `%%a`, it will  echo `something` instead of `%%a`. That's why i repeated the `FOR` variable, and should have no effect on the code.

Comment: No, you can't create a new `for` loop inside of an existing `for` loop and use the same variable; the variable will get overwritten. Just change the first `%%?` to _literally anything else_.

Comment: @SomethingDark even if i changed the second `FOR` var to `%%a`, it won't work! It returns `FOR %%a was unexpected as this time.`

Comment: Well no, `%%?` doesn't exist outside of the `for` loop it's declared in, and you are very much outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: Maybe my code is wrong, but just this line will fail: `>args.tmp FOR %%a in (%%a) do REM . SOMETHING`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210480/discussion-between-hackingaddict1337-and-somethingdark).

Answer (score 1):

Is it critical to achieve this using the Macro method, or will this solution for escaping input suffice?

```
@Echo off & CD %~dp0
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Echo("%~1">param.txt

For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%A in (param.txt) Do Set ^"param=%%~A"


Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(!param!
```

limitation being the parameter must be quoted to recieve all characters.

Accepts all standard characters

```
param "!@#$%^&*(_)%$#@ "Test" !><,./\?[]{}:;'|`~+=-"
```

Output:

[image: exmaple parameter]