# Rewrite Parameters in Windows BAT and call another command

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to process and rewrite parameters passed to a windows bat file and then call another bat file. More precisely: I want to replace backslashes in parameters by slashes.

Example:
`first.bat C:\Users\myself\test.txt anotherParam`
should call
`second.bat C:/Users/myself/test.txt anotherParam`

My attempt so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /A argCount+=1      
   call set argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x:\=/%%
)

echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do echo %%i- "!argVec[%%i]!"

call second.bat %argVec%
```

Problems:

- String replacement in loop does not work as expected
- Call of second.bat does not submit parameters

Thank you for suggestions on this topic.

Comment: Sub-string substitution only works with normal environment variables but not with `for` meta-variables, like `%%x` in your code…

Comment: Perhaps this simple solution may work: `set "params=%*"` and `call second.bat %params:\=/%`

Answer (score 2):

For simple parameters the solution can be simple

```
REM *** Avoid problems with ! in parameters
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "args=%*"

REM *** Use delayed expansion to avoid problems in search/replace
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "args=!args:\=/!"

REM *** Set delayed expansion to the "default" for second.bat
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
call second.bat %%args%%
```

BUT, if the parameters are more complex, containing a mix of quotes, ampersands or carets, it gets nasty.

Then you need [How to receive even the strangest command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4200316/463115)

If you want to handle even newlines, then you need the [syntax-error-technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689910/463115)

And then you need to modify the retrieved arguments, so they can be used for calling a secondary batch file.

At least:

```
set "args=!args:^=^^!"
set "args=!args:&=^&!"
set "args=!args:|=^|!"
set "args=!args:<=^<!"
set "args=!args:>=^>!"
set ^"args=!args:"=^"!"
```